# Am I attempting to use the FFT to correctly identify an input signal?

Tags: audio, signal-processing, fft, frequency-analysis

I'm trying to implement an FFT and I would like to ask if what I'm doing seems correct.  I'm using the GSL (GNU Science Library) for the FFT function.  I've been reading tutorials on FFT's but I would still like to ask someone to verify that I'm going in the right direction.

Here is the method that I've come up with via web material:

```
The input is a list of the amplitudes of a sin wave generated 
in audacity at 440Hz (A).  

The sample rate is 44100

# FFT points: 1024
```

Can someone explain how to choose the number of FFT points?  Or whether it matters at all.  I may have overlooked it, but I can't seem to find a method to choosing this number.
Edit: I think it is more appropriate to name this FFT window, as in you slide a window 1024 points across the samples in order to find the frequency.

```
 bin size = 44100 / 1024 = 43.066
```

after running the FFT, I have another list of amplitudes and based on what bin they are in, that is the frequency that is being detected, correct?  So in order to find the frequency of the generated signal, I want to find the highest peak?

```
A bin is defined as a peak if and only if the bin has an amplitude greater than 
2 bins to the left and 2 bins to the right.
```

Is this method on the right track to getting the frequency of the input signal?

Comment: The FFT window size depend on your needs, which you haven't told us about.  How accurate does it need to be?  The smaller the bins, the more accurate they are, and the more number crunching it takes to get them.

Comment: Sorry, I need it to be able to recognize the pitch of someones voice.   It is desired to be done in real time, I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

An FFT alone will not reliably recognize pitch, as pitch can be different from the peak frequency.  For pitch, you want to research pitch estimation algorithms, some of which use an FFT as part of the process, but many don't.

As for using an FFT for spectral estimation, the longer the FFT, the closer the FFT bin spacing in frequency, which is useful if the frequency being estimated is stationary for the duration of the window.